# My static variable CClass If I come out of main would that destroy the CClass object?

Tags: java, sql

I am trying to create a login application which connects to SQL DB to understand and learn Java. My questions regarding the program are -

- I have created CClass object in MainLoginPage class and I am using that CClass object in main() and SubmitMouseClickedbtn() but will CClass be destroyed when out of main function. The reason I have made it static is because I only want one connection to SQL DB and only want to call methods from that class hence I created just one object of that class. Correct me if my understanding is wrong?
- Also, in the mainLoginPage Class, How to compare the username from the Login Form entered by user and one from the SQL DB and check for the credentials of the user? What am I doing Wrong?

/*MAIN LOGIN PAGE CODE*/

```
    package test;

    import javax.swing.JDialog;


    public class MainLoginPage extends javax.swing.JFrame {


        public MainLoginPage() {
            initComponents();
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
        private void initComponents() {

            jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            LoginPage_jPasswordField = new javax.swing.JPasswordField();
            LoginPage_jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
            Submit = new javax.swing.JButton();
            Cancel = new javax.swing.JButton();
            SignUp = new javax.swing.JButton();
            jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

            setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            jLabel1.setText("Username: ");

            jLabel2.setText("Password: ");

            Submit.setText("Submit");
            Submit.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
                public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                    SubmitMouseClicked(evt);
                }
            });

            Cancel.setText("Cancel");

            SignUp.setText("New User? Sign Up Here");

            jLabel3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Verdana", 1, 10)); // NOI18N
            jLabel3.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
            jLabel3.setText("Login Page");
            jLabel3.setBorder(new javax.swing.border.MatteBorder(null));

            javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
            getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
            layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(28, 28, 28)
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                    .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 69, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                    .addComponent(LoginPage_jTextField1))
                                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                    .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 69, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                        .addComponent(LoginPage_jPasswordField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 183, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                                            .addComponent(SignUp, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                                .addComponent(Submit)
                                                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                                .addComponent(Cancel)))))))
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(169, 169, 169)
                            .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 166, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                    .addContainerGap(185, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            );
            layout.setVerticalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 26, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel1)
                        .addComponent(LoginPage_jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGap(29, 29, 29)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel2)
                        .addComponent(LoginPage_jPasswordField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGap(42, 42, 42)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(Submit)
                        .addComponent(Cancel))
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                    .addComponent(SignUp)
                    .addContainerGap(161, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            );

            pack();
        }// </editor-fold>                        

        private void SubmitMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                    
            // TODO add your handling code here:
            if(evt.getSource() == Submit){
                //Check if the username exists in the database and matches password
                //if true then login successful
                CClass.createSQLcommandforusernamepass("SELECT * FROM user"); //user -> name of the database

                if(LoginPage_jTextField1.getText().equals(CClass.getusername())){
                    if(LoginPage_jPasswordField.getPassword().toString().equals(CClass.getpass())){
                        System.out.println("Login Successful");
                    }
                }
            }
        }                                   


        public static void main(String args[]) {
            /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
            //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
            /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
             * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
             */
            try {
                for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                    if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                        javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainLoginPage.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainLoginPage.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainLoginPage.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainLoginPage.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            //</editor-fold>

            /* Create and display the form */
            java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    new MainLoginPage().setVisible(true);
                    CClass = ConnectionClass.getInstance();
                    CClass.createSQLconnection();
                }
            });
        }
        /*Getters*/
        public String getusername(){
            return LoginPage_jTextField1.getText();
        }

        public String getPassword(){
            return String.valueOf(LoginPage_jPasswordField.getPassword());
        }

        private static ConnectionClass CClass;
        // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
        private javax.swing.JButton Cancel;
        private javax.swing.JPasswordField LoginPage_jPasswordField;
        private javax.swing.JTextField LoginPage_jTextField1;
        private javax.swing.JButton SignUp;
        private javax.swing.JButton Submit;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
        // End of variables declaration                   
    }

/* CONNECTION CLASS */

    package test;

    import java.sql.*;
    import java.util.HashMap;

    public class ConnectionClass {

        public ConnectionClass(){
            //Default Constructor
        }
        //Creating the connection to the database
        public void createSQLconnection(){
            try{
                Conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,db_username,db_password);
                if(Conn != null) System.out.println("Connection Established");
            } catch(SQLException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        //Creating the SQL Commands for checking username and password
        public void createSQLcommandforusernamepass(String command){
            if(Conn != null){
                System.out.println("Object not null");
                try{
                    Statement stmt = Conn.createStatement();
                    ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery(command);
                    if(rset.next()){
                        // Populate the Fields
                        user = rset.getString("user_name");
                        pass = rset.getString("password");
                        userpass.put(user, pass);
                    }
                } catch(SQLException ex){
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            } 
        }

        //Get Instance
        public static ConnectionClass getInstance(){
            return new ConnectionClass();
        }

        /*Getter*/
        public String getusername(){
            return user;
        }

        /*public boolean checkmapkeyval(){
            if((userpass.containsKey(user)) && (userpass.containsValue(pass)))
               return true;
            else
                return false;
        }*/

        public String getpass(){
            return pass;
        }
        private HashMap<String, String> userpass = new HashMap<>();
        private String user;
        private String pass;
        private static Connection Conn = null;
        private String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hrdb";
        private String db_username = "root";
        private String db_password = "";
    }
```

Comment: Giant wall of code! I have not review this. But your question is easy enough. `static` means global. No. Your `static` variables will not leave scope.

Answer (score 0):

First, I couldn't ignore that for some functions you have used camel case convention but for some, you didn't, like `getusername`. About your questions:

1- It is a good practice to only have one active connection to the Database in your case but you are not doing it right in the `getInstance` method. You should define a static variable in your `ConnectionClass` which points to the instance:

```
public class ConnectionClass {            
    public static ConnectionClass instance;
    public static ConnectionClass getInstance() {
        if(ConnectionClass.instance == null)
            ConnectionClass.instance = new ConnectionClass();
        return ConnectionClass.instance;
    }

    private ConnectionClass() {
        //Default Constructor should be private to prevent any unwanted usage
    }   
}
```

2- You should use `WHEN` in your database query and pass both username and password there. Be aware that to prevent SQL injection you need to use prepared statements. Your query should look like `SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?;`. Where question marks should bind to the actual values that user inputed.